# In-house distribution constrained to several devices?

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

Is it possible to constrain an app to only 200 specific devices? I don't want that the app is installed on any device. For in-house distribution I can't select any devices ore something like that.

Is there any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An In-house distribution profile can be installed on any iOS device, So it is impossible to limit an app built from this type of profile to be installed on a certain device.

One solution to your problem(what we do in our enterprise), could be to host the app on an intranet site for OTA. The access to the site can be limited to certain number of users. That way only these users would be able to download and install this app.

P.S: And of course this solution expects the employees with access, not to to distribute the app to others.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think we have to put it on an intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Enterprise Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) is designed for. Your app is downloadable from a website rather than from the App Store.